# Custom pagestyle with titleps induce undefined control commands

Tags: header-footer, titleps

I tried using fancyhdr for many hours before giving up and switching to titleps to create headers and footers changing from odd to even pages.
It is much easier for me but as soon as I create and use a custom page style, LaTex does not recognize most of the most basic commands, such as `\clearpage` or even `\end{document}` (when it's not a fatal error).

I’ve tried the following MWE on two different systems with two different Tex editors without success, and no google search could help me.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newpagestyle{main}{
    \setheadrule{1pt}
    \setfootrule{1pt}
\sethead[\nouppercase \subsectiontitle][][\sectiontitle]
} 
\pagestyle{main}    

\begin{document}

\section{Section1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\lipsum[1-3]
\clearpage
\subsection{Subsection 2}

\end{document}
```

Removing `\pagestyle{main}` solve the problem but leaves me wihtout my headers.

Any idea? All suggestions much appreciated! :)

Comment: No page number?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for posting a good minimal example document.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. You should use braces not bracket for `\sethead`. \nouppercase is not defined with titleps:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newpagestyle{main}{%
    \setheadrule{1pt}%
    \setfootrule{1pt}%
    \sethead{\subsectiontitle}{}{\sectiontitle}%
}
\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document}

\section{Section1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\lipsum[1-3]
\clearpage
\subsection{Subsection 2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\sethead` command takes *six* arguments when used with a two-sided document if you want different odd and even headers, but you've only given it 3 (the ones for the even side) so you need to provide values for the odd side headers too.

(Since I don't know what `\nouppercase` is supposed to do, I've deleted it from the example.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[outermarks]{titleps}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newpagestyle{main}{
    \setheadrule{1pt}
    \setfootrule{1pt}
\sethead[ \subsectiontitle][][\sectiontitle] % sets even header
{}{}{} % sets odd header (put in whatever you want)
} 
\pagestyle{main}    

\begin{document}

\section{Section1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\lipsum[1-3]
\clearpage
\subsection{Subsection 2}

\end{document}
```

If you want the same header for odd and even pages, then use just the 3 argument version of `\sethead` with the arguments in `{ }` (not `[ ]`).

```
\sethead{\subsectiontitle}{}{\sectiontitle}
```

To get the subsection mark on the first page too, load the package with the option `outermarks`:

```
\usepackage[outermarks]{titleps}
```